# Unable to resolve state in Angular ui.router when URL is "home/" instead of "home"

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Below is my code for ui.router states :

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");

$stateProvider.state('account', {
      templateUrl: "/assets/views/app.html",
      abstract: true
      })
.state('account.home', {
    templateUrl: "/assets/views/index.html",
    url: '/home'
      })
```

When the user tries to go to mydomain.com/ the state resolves to account.
But when user tries to go to mydomain.com/home/ the state resolves to invalid state and therefore the user is redirected to mydomain.com/ instead of account.home state.

Expected Result :

URL: mydomain.com to resolve to account state

URL: mydomain.com/ to resolve to account state

URL: mydomain.com/home to resolve to account.home state

URL: mydomain.com/home/ to resolve to account.home state

Answer (score 0):

you can define ui-view in abstract state url,  then you can use nested states using that view. Please see the following.

```
$stateProvider
    .state('account', {
        abstract: true,
        url: "",
        template: '<div ui-view="access">',
    })
.state('account.home', {
    url: '/home',
    views: {
        'access': {  
            templateUrl: '/assets/views/index.html'
        }
     }
}
```

also you can define this

```
<div ui-view="access">
```

in you app.html as well.

Comment: This doesn't solve my problem, You check my code, "account" is already an abstract state in my $stateProvider.